# Converting NIF to OBJ in Blender 249.2 Yields Invisible Object

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, blender-2.49

I am using Three.js to render Fallout 3 objects in WebGL. The JavaScript for a similar object rendering can be found [here](http://falloutfan.com/?obj=meshes%2Fcreatures%2Fsentrybot%2Fsentrybotstatic&zoom=10&yaxis=-7). Most objects, along with their normals, have been loading just fine... Until I tried to load the brahmin...

[image: Yuck]

So, as you can see, the texture and normals are imported into Blender just fine.  But when I export the NIF file to a WaveFront OBJ file (coupled with a MTL file), it renders completely invisible. After purposely putting a typo in the MTL file for the JPG or DDS filepath, I found that it rendered as a *white* brahmin (no texture). Are there specific export settings that I am missing here (please note that I have exported these types of objects before)? Is there some significance behind the rendering being transparent? The files can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/falloutfan/code/ci/master/tree/).

*Note: there are no errors being thrown relating to textures not loading correctly.*

Finally, for further reference, here is what it looks like when trying to export this misunderstood creature:

[image]

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @gaitat, which one is it? "brahmin.jpg" is 1024, and "meatcapgore01.jpg" is 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .mtl file the value for `d` is 0 for all three materials. From the source code that parses the .mtl file:

```
// According to MTL format (http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/):
//   d is dissolve for current material
//   factor of 1.0 is fully opaque, a factor of 0 is fully dissolved (completely transparent)
```

Comment: you just made my day! That was it.  I just changed the "d" in the MTL files to 1.0 for full opacity and it turned out great. http://falloutfan.com/?obj=meshes/creatures/packbrahmin/packbrahmin&zoom=10&yaxis=-7

Comment: sorry I got caught up in the excitement.